# Request-local storage in ASP.NET (accessible to the code from IHttpModule implementation)

Tags: asp.net, iis, httpmodule

I need to have some object hanging around between two events I'm interested in: `PreRequestHandlerExecute` (where I create an instance of my object and want to save it) and `PostRequestHandlerExecute` (where I want to get to the object). After the second event the object is not needed for my purposes and should be discarded either by storage or my explicit action. So the ideal context where my object should be stored is **per request** (with guaranteed no sharing issues when different threads are serving requests... or processes/servers :) )

Take into account that actual implementation I can do is being made from a HttpModule and is supposed to be a pluggable solution for already written web apps (so the option to provide some state using static/instance variables in Global.asax doesn't look good - I will have to modify Global.asax on **every** web application).

Cache seems to be too broad for this use. I tried to see whether `httpContext.Application` (of type `HttpApplicationState`) is good for me or not, but cannot get whether it is exactly per `HttpApplication` instance or not (AFAIK you can have several instances of `HttpApplication`s used on different threads and therefore serving several requests simultaneously - then using storage shared between threads will not work correctly; otherwise I would use it because one `HttpApplication` instance serves exactly one request at a time). Something could be done with storing state on the HttpModule instances if I know for sure that it's exactly bound 1-to-1 with every `HttpApplication` instance running (but again I need a proof that `HttpApplication` instance is 1-to-1 with my HttpModule's  instance). Any valuable and reputable links on these topics are much appreciated...

Would be great to find something particularly well-suited for per request situation (because otherwise I may end up with something ulgy... probably either some 'broader' scoped storage and some hacks to have different keys in the storage for different requests, OR using a thread-local thing and in this way commit to the theory that IIS/ASP.NET will not ever serve first event from one thread and the second event from the other thread and so on)

Comment: If I saw this article before, then no question would arise... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc188942.aspx (see Interesting HttpContext Properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection. It is per Request.

Answer (score 2):

as Fahad had mentioned, `HttpContext.Current.Items` is the way to go. Be aware that it is per-request and if there are multiple threads serving the request (which sometimes happens - different modules are served by different thread) HttpContext.Current.Items is still shared between them. Some [info](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html) which you might find helpful